# Warning: Illegal string offset ' ' in

Tags: php, opencart

I am getting a `Warning: Illegal string offset 'customitem_id' in admin/controller/sale/customer.php`

and `/admin/controller/sale/customer.php on line 941Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0`

I am trying to display all of the associated custom products in a list, I am not sure what this error means. Here is the code, it works if i dont have the foreach loop, but then only one product is being displayed. I need the other 5 assigned products to also show up.

`       // Custom Item Assignment to Customer

```
    if (isset($this->request->post['customitem_id'])) {
        $data['customitem_id'] = $this->request->post['customitem_id'];
    } elseif (!empty($customer_info)) {
        $data['customitem_id'] = $customer_info['customitem_id'];
    } else {
        $data['customitem_id'] = 0;
    }
        $data['product_relateds'] = array();
        if(isset($data['customitem_id'])) {
        $related_infos = $this->model_sale_customer->getProduct($data['customitem_id']); 

        foreach($related_infos as $related_info) {
            $data['product_relateds'][] = array(
                'customitem_id' => $related_info['customitem_id'],
                'name'       => $related_info['name']
            );
          }             
       }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Other code in the tpl file looks like this

`$('input[name=\'related\']').autocomplete({
    'source': function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=catalog/customitems/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request),
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(json) {
                response($.map(json, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item['name'],
                        value: item['customitem_id']
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    'select': function(item) {
        $('input[name=\'related\']').val('');`

```
    $('#product-related' + item['value']).remove();

    $('#product-related').append('<div id="product-related' + item['value'] + '"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> ' + item['label'] + '<input type="hidden" name="customitem_id[]" value="' + item['value'] + '" /></div>')`
```

and

`<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-related"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $help_related; ?>"><?php echo $entry_addcustomitem; ?></span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" name="related" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_addcustomitem; ?>" id="input-related" class="form-control" />
                  <div id="product-related" class="well well-sm" style="height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
                    <?php foreach ($product_relateds as $product_related) { ?>
                    <div id="product-related<?php echo $product_related['customitem_id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> <?php echo $product_related['name']; ?>
                      <input type="hidden" name="customitem_id[]" value="<?php echo $product_related['customitem_id']; ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </div>
                </div> 
              </div>`

Comment: This code could not cause such error. You had to show line number on which error has occured

Comment: the error line is line: 942 `on line 941Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in` and `on line 942Warning: Illegal string offset 'customitem_id'`

Comment: added additional code to original question

Comment: So which line is 942?

Comment: 942 is the last bit of code : `'customitem_id' => $related_info['customitem_id']`

Comment: `Illegal offest` means you tried to access an element in an array that does not exist.

Comment: `$related_info` is a string not an array

Comment: Ah I see! thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown when the variable in question is a string, not an array. `$related_info` in this case. A `var_dump` of `$related_info` can help.

Comment: This **is** likely the issue - `$related_info` is a string. However this is worded as a comment, not an answer. Please editn to reword your answer, or delete it and make a comment instead

Answer (score 0):

Your first error "Illegal string offset 'customitem_id' in admin/controller/sale/customer.php" is more than likely your variable is not an array but actually a string.

Your second error "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0" indicates the variable is an array but the index 0 is same issue the variable is a string but it is empty

Simple tests below comment and uncomment each error:

> $dummyVar = "Hello";
>
> // Error => Uninitialized string offset: 5
>     //echo $dummyVar[5];
>
> // Error => Illegal string offset 'key-name'
>     //echo $dummyVar['key-name'];
>
> //Error => Undefined index: key-name
>     $dummyVar2 = array();
>     $dummyVar2[0] = 'something';
>     //echo $dummyVar2['key-name'];
>
> // Error => Uninitialized string offset: 0
>     $emptyString = '';
>     echo $emptyString[0];